# Codeigniter MySQL data in an Array

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I have a query in the model as follows :

```
public function isExistProduct($q)
    {
        if (!empty($q)) {           

            $this->db->select("store_item.item_name, store_update_stock.*, sum(qty) as qty, unit_price as up");
            $this->db->from('store_update_stock_details');
            $this->db->join('store_update_stock', 'store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id=store_update_stock.update_stock_id');
            $this->db->join('store_item', 'store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id');            
            $this->db->where("store_update_stock.status=1 and store_item.item_id= $q");
            $this->db->group_by('store_update_stock_details.unit_price','store_item.item_id');

            $q1 = $this->db->get();

            if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $q1->result_array();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

When I set store_item.item_id=1, that returns two records with different unit_prices as follows in the same item (Assume item_name=A).

```
+-----------+-----+------------+
| item_name | qty | unit_price |
+-----------+-----+------------+
| A         |  20 |       8.50 |
| A         |  50 |       7.50 |
+-----------+-----+------------+
```

That is my desired output. It is correct. Then I pass this two records to the following function in the controller.

```
public function isExistProduct()
    {    
        $id = $this->input->get('q');
        $data = $this->Item_model->isExistProduct($id);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => true, 'data' => $data));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => false));
        }
    }
```

After that expecting to show this result through the following JavaScript in my view.

```
script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("change", "#item", function () {

        $.ajax({
            'url': '<?=site_url("item/isExistProduct/?q=")?>' + $('#item').val(),
            'method': 'GET',
            'success': function (data) {


                var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jData.status == true) {

                jData.data.forEach(data => {
                    $('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
                        '<td ><span id="product" >' + jData.data[0].item_name + '</span>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + jData.data[0].item_id + '">' +
                        '</td>' +                       
                        '<td class="text-center">' + jData.data[0].qty + '</td>' +                      
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right"  disabled id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + jData.data[0].up+ '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + jData.data[0].qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +   
                        '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                    })
                }

            },
            'error': function () {

            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

When I run this Script in the view there are two records. But doubled the first record as follows.

```
+-----------+-----+------------+
| item_name | qty | unit_price |
+-----------+-----+------------+
| A         |  20 |       8.50 |
| A         |  20 |       8.50 |
+-----------+-----+------------+
```

What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help me ?

After setting up a function with data as the parameter, the following result is outs.
[image: View2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the forEach loop you should only use `data`. There is no need to reference the array. 
This line:

```
jData.data.forEach(data => {
```

sets up a function with data as the parameter.

So these lines:

```
$('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
                    '<td ><span id="product" >' + jData.data[0].item_name + '</span>' +
                    '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + jData.data[0].item_id + '">' +
                    '</td>' +                       
                    '<td class="text-center">' + jData.data[0].qty + '</td>' +                      
                    '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right"  disabled id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + jData.data[0].up+ '"></td>' +
                    '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + jData.data[0].qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +   
                    '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
                    '</tr>');
                })
```

Become:

```
$('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
                    '<td ><span id="product" >' + data.item_name + '</span>' +
                    '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + data.item_id + '">' +
                    '</td>' +                       
                    '<td class="text-center">' + data.qty + '</td>' +                      
                    '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right"  disabled id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + data.up + '"></td>' +
                    '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + data.qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +   
                    '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
                    '</tr>');
                })
```

Comment: @ NorthernDev. After setting up a function with data as the parameter as you suggested, the undefined result is showing as per my third image in the edit

Comment: @ NorthernDev. No sorry for that. Working fine after applying your suggestion